# MVC - Theory Question

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller, design-patterns, programming-languages

This is more of a theoretical question rather than language specific, but I'm mostly referring to AS3.

Let's say I have an app that shows buttons through a couple of levels of navigation.

For example `artistsAlphabetical->albums->songs` or `songsAlphabetical->song` or `albumsAlphabetical->album->song`

so we'd set up a model(Data) with all the songs (the lowest common denominator - it would have the artist/album/year etc. info within the song object)

Let's say we don't have a dataset for the albums and need to extract that from songs. or we do have a datasaet and need to match them up.

**Where should that fall under? Model or Controller?**

I can find reasons for either, but am wondering what the "correcter" way would be.

Next we have the View with all the buttons to do the sorting.

When you click on the sort button *Artists-A* -  that's the View sending a message to the Controller to do something (*get alphabetical list of artists that start with A*). The end result should be a new (paginated view if necessary) with buttons for each artist.

Which part of MVC should be responsible for each step?

**Generating a list of artists that start with A**

would it be the controller that says - 'Hey model - Artists that start with 'A' NOW!'

or, would it be more like 'Model - send me a list of all the Artists, I need to find the A-dawgs'?

essentially should the model do the sorting (and cache it if possible/needed) or should the logic be under the Controller, and the Model can store the cache?

So once we have a list of the artists, we need to create a button for all the ones that fit on the screen plus some previous/next buttons. Who should be creating the Buttons?

**Should there be a View Controller? A Sub-Controller that only deals with the logic needed to create the views? Or would the logic be part of the View?** It seems to me that the app's Controller would be all like 'not in my job description... I gave you the list you needed rest is up to you'

I feel like I'm conflicted between two views of MVC, one (**mvC**) - where the Controller is working like a motherlicker, and the Model is a glorified data holder and the view manages DisplayObjects. Or (an **MVc**) where the controller is the manager/delegator that makes sure that the Model and the View communicate properly, so that the model and view would have a fair amount of logic, and the controller would handle communication and delegate top level interaction.

While I am doing most of my stuff in AS3, I am curious how other languages would handle this. For example, in PHP Frameworks, you wouldn't need to worry about the button logic and event handling as much as with as3, where you need to watch Garbage collection, so the workload of one component there might be different than in a Cinder++, processing or actionscript app.

Comment: Are you using a MVC framework, or one of the more straight-up AS3 MVC implementations (ie, Moock's)?

Comment: this was just an example to illustrate the specifics of a question. I've tried PureMVC, but didn't like it. It's pretty rare for me to work on project simultaneously with other developers, and I find it to be quite an overkill. I don't know what Moock's implementation is, I'll have to look into it. I just divide the code into The three MVC parts and that's it. I can write out a procedure if you care to see.

Comment: I shied away from frameworks until I realized that they helped me be more consistent project-to-project, and after some serious scope-changes on projects.  Moock's MVC is what he describes in his Essential Actionscript books (not sure if he has an implementation in his AS3 book, that may be in the AS3 Design Patterns book).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know AS3.  I do both Spring MVC/Java, which really lets you do either approach, and also Ruby on Rails, which favors smart models and dumb controllers.  I like the smart model/dumb controller approach better.

So to me, anything to do with sorting and filtering the data should absolutely be done in the model, as should the process of extracting Albums from a list of Songs.

In Rails, I would put the process of creating the set of buttons in the view layer without question.  If there's actual logic involved, that would go into a view helper method.

Comment: ah, good to get some better terminology (smart models / dumb controllers) I could see how in web apps - ruby/php etc this would be the preferred case. In this example this would be almost entirely in the realm of View (except the storing and sorting of the data), as the Controller concerns itself with matters of consequence like security and smooth operation of the app as whole. In actionscript there is a lot of finer work that needs to be done to get each button to work properly plus managing memory(which is a big part of any as3 app architecture).  Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2):

As you stated already, this comes down mostly to preference, but typically I would opt for the sorting to be done in the controller.  I tend to keep my models purely about data storage and reduce the amount of functionality in them.  So in your example, the model's job would be to hold all of the artists' data, and the controller's job would be to extract the artists starting with "A" from that data, and subsequently passing that sorted data to the view.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use traditional MVC anymore, so I tend to think more in terms of PureMVC (proxies, mediators, and commands) now.

In general, I tend towards more functional proxies (think model) where the data gets abstracted (for the typical reasons for abstracting data).  So, in your cases, there would be a MusicLibrary proxy, and would probably have methods like byArtist(), byTitle(), byRandom(), etc.

In a PureMVC app, a sequence for your scenario would look like:

1. Component catches mouse click and sends Mouse.CLICK
2. Mediator wrangling the component catches event, and sends notification SORTBY_ARTIST_CLICKED
3. Command which is requesting notification of SORTBY_ARTIST_CLICKED, calls the the byArtist() method on the proxy, builds a notification NEW_MUSIC_LIST w/ the data and sends it
4. Mediator requesting notification of NEW_MUSIC_LIST then does its thing and updates the components is is wrangling

I think this would align with what JacobM describes as smart model / dumb controller.  I think that this approach leads better resuse, and also better isolates impact from chages.

I will say that in general, if I have different views of the same data (like in your case), I will use commands to push out the data, but if a view just gets a data update I will often have the view just pull the data from a proxy.